# Expresso Store: Can a promo code discount be applied BEFORE taxes are applied?

Tags: expresso-store, discounts

can a promo code percentage  discount be applied BEFORE taxes are applied in Expresso Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promo code always applies to the pre-tax price, however Store will always assume that there is some tax which needs to be discounted as well (otherwise there would be too much tax for your order).

The only time this is a problem is if you have some tax-free products in your order, because the promo code will discount too much tax, since it has no way of knowing which products were actually discounted.

That said, a percentage off the order discount shouldn't matter whether it is applied to the pre or post tax prices, right?